# What does $var = value actually return?

Tags: php, variables, initialization

This seems like a very mysterious part of PHP to me, and I was wondering if someone could clarify because the manual doesn't seem to include this (or I just couldn't find it anywhere).

What would some of these things return?

```
if($c = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)){
 echo 'Success';
}else{
 echo 'Failure';
}
```

Would this always echo 'Success' because $c is successfully assigned to true or false? I'm wondering if I can do this or if I have to define $c on the previous line.

Thanks.

Comment: mysql_connect returns either an object or false. $c in this case will have the MySql object on success and a boolean false on failure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is mentioned in [*Assignment Operators*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php):

> The value of an assignment expression is the value assigned. That is, the value of "$a = 3" is `3`.

So `$c = ...` will result in `true` if `true` is assigned to `$c` and in `false` if `false` is assigned.

That is also the reason why iterating over query results

```
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array(...)))
```

works.

Answer (score 4):

**When in doubt, build a test-case!**

Build a test-case:

```
if ( $c = true ) {
  echo 'Success';
} else {
  echo 'No Success';
}
```

Run this online: http://codepad.org/jxylNzOu

You'll note that the first block will only be executed if the conditions turn up `true` (or what PHP evaluates as `true` when asked), so it's not asking if a value was successfully applied to `$c`, but rather whether the value applied to `$c` is `true`.

**Regarding your specific example...**

If your case, where you're attempting to open a connection to MySQL, `$c` will be `true` if the connection is made, resulting in the first block of the `if-statement` being ran. Otherwise, if no connection is made, `$c` will be false, making the condition of the `if-statement` false, resulting in the running of the `else` block.

According to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) for `mysql_connect()`, one of two things can be returned from this function.

1. A MySQL Link Identifier (if a connection is made)
2. `FALSE`, indicating a failure to make a connection.

So there's no difference between the following code examples

```
$conn = mysql_connect( $host, $user, $pass );
if ( $conn ) { /*...*/ }
```

And

```
if ( $conn = mysql_connect( $host, $user, $pass ) {
  /*...*/
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: `$c` will be a *resource* if the connection was made, which evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Actually `$c` will not be true but will be a connection resource. Better to say `$c` will be `!== FALSE` in case of success or `FALSE` on failure

Comment: +1 to the both of you; you're both *technically* correct :) I'm aware that an actual boolean isn't returned on success, but that when evaluated a valid link identifier triggers the `true` results as opposed to the `false` results.

Answer (score 0):

It does not always echo 'Success'. PHP first assigns the result of `mysql_connect` to `$to` then evaluates boolean value of `$to`. But it's better to use this way to ensure the understandability:

```
$c = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)
if($to) {
    echo 'Success';
} else{
    echo 'Failure';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a "weakly typed" language which means php doesn't require (nor support it for that matter) explicit type declaration of variables.

Pay attention to consufe or evaluate 0 1 as true/false (boolean value)

Take this case as sample:

```
$s = "0"; //String s = '0'
$res = strstr($s,'0'); //Search the character zero into the string $s
if ($res){
  echo "Zero found!";
}else{
  echo "Zero not found!"
}
//Hey!! Whats up!!?? Zero is not found!
```

This is because zero, which is the returned value of the function `strstr`,  is evaluated as  `FALSE` producing in some cases unexpected results.

The correct way is to use the `Not Identical` operator `!==` where value and **type** is compared

The previous example should be:

```
$s = "0"; //String s = '0'
$res = strstr($s,'0'); //Search the character zero into the string $s
if ($res !== FALSE){//Check for value AND type
  echo "Zero found!";
}else{
  echo "Zero not found!"
}
//yeah now it works!
```

So in your case I would write the if statement as:

```
if(($c = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)) !== FALSE){
 echo 'Success';
}else{
 echo 'Failure';
}
```

Comment: Those are quite separate issues from what the OP is asking. `strstr` *may* return a boolean `false` or *success values* that *may* evaluate to `false`. `mysql_connect` doesn't have that problem, it'll return a resource which evaluates to `true` on success or a boolean `false` on failure.

Comment: Yes I agree, just to clarify that the `if-statement` must be written paying attention about the returning value and type of the function